# php parse xml problems

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to parse an xml generated by excel, but i'm hitting a stag.
I cant get anywhere below the Workbook node:

```
$benregxml = simplexml_load_file('00_ben_reg_main.xml');
$wrkbook = $benregxml->Workbook->Worksheet;
print_r($wrkbook);
```

If i log Workbook, that works (output is SimpleXMLElement Object ( )).

I'm actually trying to get the row node, but nothing i try appears to work.

Excel XML code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet" ?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
    <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <Author>Ognen Plavevski</Author>
        <LastAuthor>Ognen Plavevski</LastAuthor>
        <Created>2013-05-24T20:28:09Z</Created>
        <Version>14.00</Version>
    </DocumentProperties>
    <OfficeDocumentSettings xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
        <AllowPNG/>
    </OfficeDocumentSettings>
    <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
        <WindowHeight>10035</WindowHeight>
        <WindowWidth>22995</WindowWidth>
        <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
        <WindowTopY>45</WindowTopY>
        <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
        <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
    </ExcelWorkbook>
    <Styles>
        <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
            <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/> <Borders/> <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="11" ss:Color="#000000"/> <Interior/> <NumberFormat/> <Protection/>
        </Style>
        <Style ss:ID="s62">
            <Protection ss:Protected="0"/>
        </Style>
    </Styles>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet1">
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="19" ss:ExpandedRowCount="101" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
            <Row>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PARENT_RECORD_ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PARENT_PAGE_ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">PARENT_ELEMENT_ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CREATED_DATE</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CREATED_BY</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CREATED_LOCATION</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">CREATED_DEVICE_ID</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">MODIFIED_DATE</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">MODIFIED_BY</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">MODIFIED_LOCATION</Data>
                </Cell>
                <Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
                    <Data ss:Type="String">MODIFIED_DEVICE_ID</Data>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <PageSetup>
                <Header x:Margin="0.3" />
                <Footer x:Margin="0.3" />
                <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75" />
            </PageSetup>
            <Selected/>
            <Panes>
                <Pane>
                    <Number>3</Number>
                    <RangeSelection>R1C1:R101C19</RangeSelection>
                </Pane>
            </Panes>
            <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
            <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
        </WorksheetOptions>
    </Worksheet>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15"></Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <PageSetup>
                <Header x:Margin="0.3" />
                <Footer x:Margin="0.3" />
                <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75" />
            </PageSetup>
            <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
            <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
        </WorksheetOptions>
    </Worksheet>
    <Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet3">
        <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15"></Table>
        <WorksheetOptions xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
            <PageSetup>
                <Header x:Margin="0.3" />
                <Footer x:Margin="0.3" />
                <PageMargins x:Bottom="0.75" x:Left="0.7" x:Right="0.7" x:Top="0.75" />
            </PageSetup>
            <ProtectObjects>False</ProtectObjects>
            <ProtectScenarios>False</ProtectScenarios>
        </WorksheetOptions>
    </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$benregxml = simplexml_load_file('00_ben_reg_main.xml');
$wrkbook = $benregxml->Worksheet[0]->Table->Row;
print_r($wrkbook);
```

It's your level that is the problem and of course that you have 3 Worksheet tags (so it's an array). The workbook tag is the head, so 
`$benregxml = Workbook` from the start

**UPDATE**

```
$benregxml = simplexml_load_file('00_ben_reg_main.xml');
$cells = $benregxml->Worksheet[0]->Table->Row[0];
//You need Row[0] because Row will return object, but you want just the content, 
    //which is the array of cells.
echo "<pre>"; print_r($cells); echo "</pre>";

echo "<br>----------------------------------------------------------------<br>";
foreach( $cells as $cell ) {

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($cell); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Just to clarify, Row returns `SimpleXMLElement Object` which as you see in the output consists of an array of `SimpleXMLElement Object` of cells. If you want the object you want Row, but if you want the actual array you need Row[0]. If you find this difficult to understand I advise you to check the json format. It will help a lot. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a better way to debug the output other than print_r?

Comment: You got two problems. Worksheet[0] was one. The second was that $benregxml = Workbook from loading, so $benregxml->Workbook->Worksheet[0] wouldn't work either. No, I'm afraid there isn't. At least I don't know another way.

Comment: One more question.
I'm trying to iterate the rows and cells, but the cells bit doesnt work:
foreach ($rows as $row):
 $cells = $row->Cell;
 foreach ($cells as $cell):
  print_r($cell);  
 endforeach;
endforeach;

Comment: Hey I remembered a better way of formating the output for debug. Also in this example you have only one row. I'll update my answer in a little bit and you will get the idea.

Comment: Nope, I've made a mistake. Check again my code. This is the right one.
With the new format, you will be able to see the output pretty clear and if you play with it a little you will understand the flow.